# I am frustrated that this question was putted on hold

Tags: discussion

I think it's enough to read my comments to see that another approach than the one Gilles took, can be taken:

[Main usages of mask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479452/main-usages-of-mask)

Comment: What are you looking for in this Meta question?

Comment: @JeffSchaller revision of my last 2 comments and discussion in the approach Gilles displayed. I think it's unjust to put this question on hold. IMO after all the "mess" this "question" went through I think at least some tips on how to improve it in its current form should be given there as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I voted as unclear because I don't know where to start.

The title said, at various points (I'm not sure what it was when I voted on it):

- What is the difference between mask and umask?
- Understanding the possible difference between mask and umask

The body had hyperlinks to "bit" and "stream" and "bitwise operation" that could have added relevance, but were just definitions (that anyone could look up). IMHO, adding links brings some importance (focus, or important background) to those terms, but here -- IMHO, they're distracting as hyperlinks. Use your own words to describe your understanding of them.

The question then broadens in scope by saying "used ... upon basically any type of code", which is a tenuous claim, IMHO.

The final (at that point) part of the body asked the Question:

> How does a mask differs from umask, if at all?

... where you haven't demonstrated any part of your understanding of `umask` for an answerer to be able to start from. It sounds like you're making a claim that they're the same and then asking for someone to make a counterpoint, but you never provided your definition of `umask`.

My best interpretation of your question is that it asks what the `umask` command does, in which case it's a duplicate of [Why doesn't umask change execute permissions on files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287278/117549) or [How umask works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211481/117549) or others. If you're unclear on how umask works, my suggestion would be to play with it on some test files, read the [umask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umask) tagged questions, and then ask about a surprising or confusing result you had.

Your revised question, after un-doing the graffiti -- please don't deface your own questions, there's a delete link for the question, if you need it -- now reads in the same general, confusing way. You ask:

> Are there any other important use cases of mask streams?

where you seem to make up the phrase "mask stream" by combining "bit stream" with "bitmask" and then asking an open-ended question about what they might be used for.

Ask an answerable question where you lay out what you know and where your knowledge ends (or surprise begins). Questions are free, so focus one Question on one question: if you want to know what how a umask is different from a mask, then define those two to your understanding and ask *that*; if you want to know what "mask streams" are used for, I'm not sure how to help you. It's hard to use someone else's definition and extrapolate it, and this site isn't geared towards open-ended questions.

Comment: Well, I wanted to delete the question but couldn't. I lost 12 rep points because of that lousy question. I can edit it, but it seems everyone have lost any interest in re-checking it after it is changed.

Comment: You may face an uphill battle, but it's not pre-destined to end in failure. Consider all the [valuable feedback](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479452/main-usages-of-mask#comment877004_479452) you've received and edit the question -- importantly! -- in one session, so that it re-enters the review queue. It will (hopefully) be seen by enough people who (hopefully) now agree that it's answerable and will vote to reopen it.  No need to leave a rant or trace of negative history in the question; the edit history is there for anyone to see, but the Question should be judged as it ends up.

Comment: I thank you so much for all that help dear Jeff. This is NOT common and I find this graceful, communal and inspirational. I really am full of gratitude ! I tried to edit the question providing `man bash` segments I didn't understand and ask a (hopefully) narrower question comprised of two sub questions.